# Chrome Extension open new page on click, browses to wrong location on shelf in ChromeOS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a very basic extension that launches a page when the icon is clicked. I pushed it out via Google Enterprise. It works flawlessly when you click the icon in Chrome. However, when you click the icon on the shelf (bottom start area of the OS) it launches and browses to chrome://extensions

Not sure I under why this is happening?

### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "App",
    "description": "",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0.0.2",
    "author": {
        "name": "Me",
        "email": "myemail@me.com"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"

    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

### background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://url.com/to/open" });
});
```

I'm thinking it's because I am using `chrome.browserAction`. Is there something different I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: How did you add the icon on the shelf?

Comment: The icon is being pushed by Google Admin Console. I wonder if manually adding it does the same thing.. hm.

Comment: Okay, I have been trying to figure this out for two days now. It looks like Extensions are not meant to be pinned.. that's frustrating.